# send and excecute scripts via putty(ssh) connection

Tags: bash, ssh, putty

I have access to some machines via putty(ssh).
Sometimes I need to run scripts on those machines. Is there a simple and secure way to send files from my computer to the machine via ssh connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scp` to copy files via ssh:

```
scp local_file remote_machine:/target/location
```

You can also run command directory though ssh:

```
ssh remote_machine 'echo 1 > remote_file'
```

And even pipe to ssh then continue on remote:

```
cat local_file | ssh remote_machine 'cat > remote_file'
```

Comment: Forgot to tell, sometimes I'm using windows and sometimes linux, this command relevant for both of the OS?

Comment: The first and second should work for both Windows & Linux